# How to develop and use a Javascript Date Calendar in PHP web application?

Tags: php, javascript, html, date, calendar

I would like to create and add a calendar object plus select elements(comboboxes)  for Day-Month-Year using HTML and JavaScript in a PHP web application.

This calendar is common used for the user input for dates like:-
From Date : 01/11/2010 - To Date : 10/11/2010

The calendar should have a nice-look, displayed automatically when the user changes the date comboboxes or presses an attached link and may work in parallel with the date combboxes so the user can select using the comboboxes or the calendar without conflict.

How to do that as I searched a lot of web sites but I did noty find a suitable calendar.

Also, how to make this calendar as a library or class so I can use and edit it in any web page in my web application especially that I need to use it frequently ?

Note : Please I want examples using Simple JavaScript without using JQuery..

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Thanks for the Advice .. I already revise the answers and choosed the more suitable and informative ones ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input) is one of the cool JQuery Date Input plugin.
The one can do customize and localize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer although I would like to do that using JavaScript only without using jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-search). Visit the page and you will find many more ways to customize it.